# How to move image separately from markers in Plotly.js (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plot, plotly

I'm using https://plotly.com/javascript/line-and-scatter/

There is a layout with image and a lot of markers (see screenshot). I need to move an image regardless to all markers, grid and other stuff of Plotly.

So user can do `mousedown` and according to movement of mouse background image will change it position.

[Demonstration what should me moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UcIg.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, see how do I ask a good question [ask], and also add some code.

Comment: I'm not sure what code should i add, because it's clearly plotly.js (https://plotly.com/javascript/line-and-scatter/). And i'm just asking - is there is a way to move background picture regardless to other elements?